Isomorphism $\mathbb{A}^2 \to \mathbb{A}^2$
This exercise is taken from the notes of Gathmann of Algebraic Geometry, in particular it is the point d) of the exercise 4.13 of the version 2021/2022.

If $f:\mathbb{A}^2 \to \mathbb{A}^2$ is an isomorphism then $f$ is affine linear, i.e. it is of the form $f(x)=Ax+b$ for some $A\in Mat(2\times 2,K)$ and $b \in K^2$.

I don't understand why this is true. An isomorphism $f:\mathbb{A}^2 \to \mathbb{A}^2$ corresponds to an isomorphism $f^*:K[x,y] \to K[x,y]$ (as $K$-algebras). But the automorphisms of $K[x,y]$ are composition of something of the form

$x \mapsto x, y \mapsto y+h(x)$
$x \to x+ h(y), y \mapsto x$
$x \mapsto a_{11}x+a_{12}y+a_{13}, y \mapsto a_{21}x+a_{22}y+a_{23}$ with $a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{22}\neq 0$

Turning back to morphisms $f:\mathbb{A}^2 \to \mathbb{A}^2$, only the third case is what we are looking for. But what can I do for the other two cases? How are they linear?

The question doesn't ask you to proof this. It asks

Are the following statements true or false?

I think you have solved this.
